# regex for extracting HTML tag child elements?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following code in HTML string.

```
<h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>

</h3><h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>

</h3>
```

and i want to extract the following tag:

```
    <a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
    <span>get the content</span>
    </a>
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>
```

I have written following regex :

```
<h3[^>]+?>(.*)<\/h3>
```

But it is returning wrong results :

```
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>

</h3><h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">
<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">
<span>get the content</span>
</a>
```

Please help me to extract the tags.

Comment: I think [***Tony the pony***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) would dislike this !!!

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*`. The latter is greedy and will match from the first <h3> to the last </h3>, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: @adeneo - thx for the link :) , but I think in this case with a defined subset (H3 tag here) - it's manageable with regExp and without getting _infected_ ...

Comment: @michaPau - the point is, it's just so easy to parse the HTML and do `document.querySelectorAll('a')`

Comment: please upvote the answer too if it was useful :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
<h3[^>]+?>([^$]+?)<\/h3>
```

Example here:

https://regex101.com/r/pQ5nE0/2

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```js
function getA(str) {
  var regex = /<a\s+[\s\S]+?<\/a>/g;
  while (found = regex.exec(str)) {
    document.write(found[0] + '<br>');
  }
}

var str = '<h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">\n' +
  '<span>get the content</span>\n' +
  '</a>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '</h3><h3 class="large lheight20 margintop10">\n' +
  '<a href="https://google.com" class="marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink">\n' +
  '<span>get the content</span>\n' +
  '</a>\n' +
  '\n' +
  '</h3>';
getA(str);
```

Comment: you don't need to add "+" in each line and keep quoting again and again in js, simply add backslash at the end of line

Comment: also, what happens to other links on the page, other than within h3 ones, they get matched too!